# How can I put Fedora GUI onto Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, gui, fedora

Okay, I'm pretty new to Linux-based systems, so if I say something wrong or ask something dumb, please bear with me.

I have a project for school that requires some extensive work inside of the latest version of Fedora including screenshots of rather specific things. The VM system at my school runs Fedora 20 like a snail high on paint fumes, and my laptop's VirtualBox doesn't recognize the ISO I got from the official Fedora site, so I feel like I'm out of alternatives aside from formatting over Ubuntu. I'd rather not do that, as I rather enjoy this distro.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. At my login screen, I have the much appreciated option of selecting between a couple of GUI's--specifically, Ubuntu, GNOME, and Cinnamon. I would like to get the Fedora GUI added to this list, but I don't know where to start or if it's even an option.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Just run Fedora of a live CD. Or install a dual boot. Just do the assignment and you'll learn more.

Comment: Have you tried the `Network Install CD` from the [Get Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora-all) website?

Comment: @don.joey I tried running Fedora from a live disk. When I ran the hardware check, I came back incompatible. I think that leaves Dual Booting out of the question as well. And unfortunately, the assignment is just really basic operation of the OS. Change your background/make a new file type simple. I just needed to get _into_ the right OS so I could get the screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora what you have seen is most probably use Gnome 3 Desktop. So we simply have to install it in Ubuntu.

Open the Terminal and execute this command:

> sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment gnome-session-flashback

Now logout and choose "Gnome" as the session, and login again:

[image]

You should get something like this:

[image]

Get Fedora wallpapers form [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/F20_Artwork/Submissions/Supplemental_Wallpapers).

Comment: @Dareleth however this will not give you _exact_ Fedora GUI, because it uses updated version of GNOME. Also commands can compromise you. Hope that your teachers will not see the change.

Comment: It's not exact, but it's the closest thing I've got. Honestly, I don't think this instructor will know the difference. She's a little blank on Linux systems. Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you can post a screen shot of the system, we will be able to help more :)

Comment: Actually, @Naveen, that version of GNOME worked perfectly. The only difference I can spot in the GUI is the top right corner. Fedora compresses all the clickable options down to one button whereas GNOME maintains multiple buttons with their own drop down menus. And the only other discrepancy was one line in the terminal. The command to become root in GNOME was `sudo su` instead of the `su root` command the instructor gave us.

Comment: @Dareleth: I'm confused. The one with the single menu at top right is called **Gnome Shell** It is the latest one. If you have more than one menu items on top right, then you are using *Gnome Classic* which is the old version. **su root** is preferable because it makes sense (switch user to root)

Comment: @Naveen are you sure? `su root` seems not the correct Ubuntu method to me (since we do not know the root password) Ubuntu = sudo su.

Comment: In that case you are correct :)

Comment: @Naveen `su root` always gives me a `su: Authentication failure` message. And I think I may just be using Gnome Classic. Either way, it looks almost identical to what I needed.

Comment: If you are interested, this explains all the stuff about sudo & su : http://mylinuxbook.com/sudo-vs-su-in-ubuntu-linux/